# My Notebook always thinks there is a VGA monitor plugged in

Tags: connector, vga

Well, my notebook started behaving weirdly recently and I found out it always thinks there is a VGA monitor plugged in, it would show up on my OS as 'unknown display'. Also, when I do plug in an actual display, the screen works but is very very dark - tested with multiple VGA monitors.

The onboard screen works when I'm inside an OS, but not on the BIOS - it defaults to displaying only on an external display is connected, so I get blank until I reach an OS.

After reading about the VGA pinout and the DDC protocol, I tested the input pins against the GND pin, and found out two of them (pins 4 and 11), which should be N/C (so, probably pulled up), are exactly at GND's level. Pin 12 is about 4.8V, as expected. I've tried shorting pins 11 and 4 to pin 12, but nothing happened. Is there a way I can fix this or at least determine the issue with more certainty?

Comment: Please let us know the laptop's model. Things to try : (1) [Hard Reset](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01684768), (2) Refresh to the latest BIOS. If nothing helps, then I would go for a hardware problem with the display adapter - is it on-board or do you have dual adapters ?

Comment: It is an K55VD, Asus manufacturer, tried both already

Comment: [This model](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/K55VD/specifications/) has the NVIDIA GeForce 610M and does not have an on-board adapter. It also probably has no guarantee. A good test would be to replace the NVIDIA card. Taking the laptop to a professional workshop might be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tested the input pins against the GND pin, and found out two of them (pins 4 and 11), which should be N/C (so, probably pulled up), are exactly at GND's level.

You are correct, [pulling pins 4 and 11 low](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/295718/72179) is how VGA screens tell the host they are connected. Your laptop should weakly pull these pins HIGH for this detection mechanism to work. Pulling them LOW is consistent with the issue you're having.

> I've tried shorting pins 11 and 4 to pin 12, but nothing happened.

Pin 12 is basically an i2c data line, meaning it is weakly pulled HIGH on both sides, and each side can pull it LOW to communicate. Connecting it to pins 11 and 4 most probably pulls pin 12 LOW as well.

So, something is broken in your laptop. Most probably the IC connected to VGA plug got damaged, resulting in a latch-up on signals connected to VGA pins 11 and 4. Don't try to pull these pins HIGH with a strong signal (i.e. connect them to +5V without a resistor), as this will most probably fry the damaged IC completely. Note that latched up chips tend to get worse as time goes by, because they often overheat.

Short of replacing the video adapter (if it is replaceable in your laptop) I doubt it will be possible to repair your laptop at home, without special equipment for BGA soldering and a good schematic.